# The RPC call or parameters have been disabled

Tags: solana-program, rust, nft

I'm facing an error while fetching the details of all NFTs using a wallet address.
It's working fine on the devnet, but when I switch to the mainnet, it shows an issue. Could you please clarify the problem I encountered?

error:
Error: 410 Gone:  {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "error":{"code": 410, "message": "The RPC call or parameters have been disabled."} }
Facing.

code:

```
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection);
  const owner = new PublicKey("walletAddress");
  const allNFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner({ owner });
  console.log("All Nfts:", allNFTs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some RPC calls are disabled on some RPC endpoints. If you use a quicknode (or other provider) RPC url, this should work great.

I've faced the same problem with "getParsedProgramAccounts" call, and it is probable that metaplex uses it to get the data you need

Comment: Yup, it's work on this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Under the hood, `findAllByOwner` uses `getProgramAccounts`, which might be disabled on the public `mainnet-beta` endpoint.

[Helius](https://www.helius.dev/) is an option that provides mainnet/devnet rpc endpoints with free tier.

You would then just need to update the connection with your rpc url.

```
const connection = new Connection(<Your RPC Url>);
```

Comment: Thank you for informing me about Helius. I was using QuickNode for RPC, and it was functioning on certain RPCs while not on others. After investigating all the RPCs, it is now operational on some of the RPCs endpoints.